# Nodejs - Get content from external website

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

i wrote a simple website that returns a random 4-digit number every time you reload. Okay so i want to read that digit through `Node.js`.. Googled couple times and found out that `axios` and `fs` was my best bet..

My website: `SOLVED`

The website above works on my browser.. might not on yours.. so i made a temp website for this.. it still doesn't work as expected: 
`SOLVED`

I came up with this:

```
let axios = require('axios');
let cheerio = require('cheerio');
let fs = require('fs'); 

axios.get('http://thedico.com/third.php')
    .then((response) => {
        if(response.status === 200) {
          const html = response.data;
          const $ = cheerio.load(html); 
            res.send("Status returned 200...!");
    }
    }, (error) => console.log(error) res.send("error...!"));

    res.send("Done...!");
```

I use this code with `Google Cloud Functions` a.k.a `gCloud` but this code nor prints a output or returns my website data.. What should i do?

Things i made sure of:

- My website is up and loading time is around `440MS` on normal speed.
- My 'gCloud' billing is set and enabled
- everything works fine on manual reload

Thanks

Comment: Is the site up and running? You're posting an URL here but it appears unreachable. Not sure if you really want to post an URL here, but if you're expecting it to be world readable ATM it just is not. So I think you're problem is either with the "other" listing or the service, because if that returns nothing then "this" listing simply is not going to do anything.

Comment: @NeilLunn.. i had cloudflare.. just removed it.. please check :http://thedico.com/third.php

Comment: Never saw the cloudfare one. The NEW URL is the one I'm using it **returns nothing**. Timing out to be more concise. That typically implies something is breaking before the response is set. Domain resolves fine. the `third.php` page does not

Comment: http://prntscr.com/jb6n6w ..  are you sure. the number is quite small

Comment: Possitive. Timeout. Nothing. Zilch. Really this is not for "US" to check anyway. You need to check these things yourself. So just telling you the very simple reason for the fail.

Comment: Is this the full code? I mean, `res` is undefined and keep in mind, http call is async. This line should not be there. `res.send("Done...!");`

Comment: @RitwickDey You're correct in observing that, but the current comment stream is focusing on *" ... but this code nor prints a output or returns my website data..."* which I suspect is because the request is hanging there waiting for the server to respond from the very first line.

Comment: @NeilLunn -- @ritwek res comes from this `exports.reply = (req, res) => {}` my reply function

Comment: The point that was being made there is you need to `res.send()` **within** the `.then()` resolver of the promise chain. Otherwise it's just going to return before the promise resolves. But I'm still getting a connection timeout. You might not see it from your desktop, but there's a strong chance your GCF is getting the same timeout if you see no response from it at all.

Comment: @NeilLunn. tried on couple different browser's it works fine here i don't know why

Comment: @NeilLunn.. Just made a temp website.. can you check this please? https://alexandrarawand.000webhostapp.com/index.php i am really sorry

Comment: @KimberlyLife Do you get your answer or not?

Comment: @Dipakchavda.. not yet

Comment: @KimberlyLife It returns me a data to my local machine so what do you want actually now what is an issue really not getting much.

Comment: @KimberlyLife Do you wanted to send back to server or any other place?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169985/discussion-between-dipak-chavda-and-kimberly-life).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried with axios and request as well it is working fine now. As well you have a couple of bugs in your code.

```
const request = require("request");
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const fs = require('fs');
```

> with Request module

```
request('https://alexandrarawand.000webhostapp.com/index.php', function (error, response, html) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        // Get text 
        console.log("------- with request module -------")
        console.log($.text());
        // Get HTML 
        //console.log($.html());
    }
});
```

> with Axios module

```
axios.get('https://alexandrarawand.000webhostapp.com/index.php')
    .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            const html = response.data;
            const $ = cheerio.load(html);
            // Get text 
            console.log("------- with axios module -------")
            console.log($.text());
            // Get HTML 
            //console.log($.html());
        }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        throw new Error(err);
    });
```

Hope it may help you.

Comment: A bit late, but if someone is still searching this page, axios module will only work if the endpoint gives you the content by its own. and there is big risk that you will be blocked by CORS policy. axios is usually referred as AJAX technique and is used for API calls, so I would go for `request`

Comment: Request package has deprecated, hence rather we should go with node-fetch, axios, got module.